# Cannot open firefox in Docker container

Tags: selenium, firefox, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a selenium test inside a Docker container. I created the image on top of a base image of Oracle Linux 6.7 and with Firefox 24 on it. Set the Display in the entry-point script which also runs the selenium test. But when it runs the tests, it errors out saying

```
  [java] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
 [java] *** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: startup
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous9132988696593276996webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
 [java] *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
 [java] *** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: startup
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous9132988696593276996webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
 [java] *** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
 [java] process 149: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to open "/var/lib/dbus/machine-id": No such file or directory
 [java] See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
 [java]   D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
```

This is how I set the display in the entry point script

```
#Set the Display
vncserver :1
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Can anyone please advise on what I might be doing wrong?

Additional Info and Troubleshooting I did: 
I thought this might be the version compatibility issue with Firefox and Selenium (using selenium 2.44.0 and firefox 24), but looks like it is not.

1. This test runs fine with the same version of firefox and selenium when ran from my VM. fails only if I run it as a docker image.
2. Tried to upgrade the firefox version to 44, but did not help.
3. Exposed the right ports in my docker file. 5900,5901,5902,5903.

Comment: are you using the official docker repo?  if so, what version(s) and commands are you running?

Comment: No, I am not using the official repo.

Comment: so you aren't using http://hub.docker.com/r/selenium projects.

Comment: I built the image from scratch. Used Oracle Linux as base and installed other relevant packages including firefox. Exposed the ports. Pointed to an entrypoint script. The entry point script runs the selenium tests.

Comment: gotcha.. i'm the maintainer of the selenium docker repositories so thought i'd ask :)  don't think i can help ya with that error. never seen it before.

Comment: so you aren't using hub.docker.com/r/selenium projects - No, I am not using this repo.

Comment: cool, thats ok :)